# Prompt Menu in Ruby

Tags: ruby, menu

I'm trying to create a simple prompt menu in Ruby. I'm not expert in Ruby but I'm trying to code something similar to the prompt menu in others languages like C/C++ but my code isn't working right, I'm geting a infinity loop on the user input and isn't calling the function.

Heres my code:

```
begin
  puts "Option 1"
  puts "Option 2"
  puts "Option 3"
  puts ""
  command = gets.chomp

    loop do   
    case command
    when 1
      functionname(arg1, arg2)
    when 2
      functionname2(arg1, arg2)
    end

    end
end
```

Please, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ask for an option once, simply get rid of the `loop` (once ≠ loop):

```
puts ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", ""].join $/

case command = gets.chomp
when 1
  functionname(arg1, arg2)
when 2
  functionname2(arg1, arg2)
else
  raise "Unknown option"
end
```

To request an option many times, ask inside `loop`:

```
loop do
  puts ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", ""].join $/

  case command = gets.chomp
  when 1
    functionname(arg1, arg2)
  when 2
    functionname2(arg1, arg2)
  else
    break # break loop
  end
end
```